# Excel: Passing an array in a user defined function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, parameters, user-defined-functions

How to pass an array as a parameter for a user defined function in MS Excel VBA?

Eventually I want to test that if a given date (dateDay) is in several ranges of dates (arrayVacation):

```
Function CB_IsInRangeArr(dateDay As Date, ParamArray arrayVacation() As Variant) As Boolean

    ' Test that the array is in the form of 2 columns and n rows / if not send back an error
    If (UBound(arrayVacation, 1) <> 2) Then
        CB_IsInRangeArr = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    Else
        CB_IsInRangeArr = TRUE
    End If
End Function
```

Yet already at this stage, the function does not work properly. It returns #VALUE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, i added a function

```
Public Function CB_IsInRangeArr(c As Date, range As range) As Boolean
Dim iRow As Integer

    For iRow = 1 To range.Rows.Count
        Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date
        startDate = range.Cells(iRow, 1)
        endDate = range.Cells(iRow, 2)
        If (startDate <= c And endDate >= c) Then
            CB_IsInRangeArr = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next iRow
End Function
```

this allows you to add the date ranges, and a cell for the date to check.

then the formula in the cell is

```
=CB_IsInRangeArr(C1,A1:B2)
```

with c1 being the date to check, and a1:b2 the date ranges.

Please ask if i can assist further.

Answer (score 2):

Paramarray creates an array of variants with each element holding the parameter:
Try something like this

```
Function CB_IsInRangeArr(dateDay As Date, ParamArray arrayVacation() As Variant) As Variant

    Dim nParams As Long
    Dim vRangeValues As Variant
    Dim jParam As Long
    Dim j As Long

    nParams = UBound(arrayVacation) - LBound(arrayVacation) + 1
    If nParams &le 0 Then Exit Function
    On Error GoTo Fail

    For jParam = LBound(arrayVacation) To UBound(arrayVacation)

        vRangeValues = arrayVacation(jParam).Value

        For j = LBound(vRangeValues) To UBound(vRangeValues)
            If (vRangeValues(j, 1) &le dateDay And vRangeValues(j, 2) &ge dateDay) Then
                CB_IsInRangeArr = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j

    Next jParam

    Exit Function
Fail:
    CB_IsInRangeArr = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```